# How to automize Shannon's Entropy calculation using a MM function

Tags: matrix, code-review

With the following `code`, I calculate Shannon's Entropy function `HH1` for a given matrix `mat`. This `code` works just fine, but I need to replicate the same calculations for a large number of matrices. It will be convenient if the following calculations are combined in a MMA function called `ShannonEntropy[...]:=`, which accepts raw matrices as inputs, such matrices as `mat1`, `mat2`, etc.

```
ClearAll[n, mat, bbMM1, HH1];
SeedRandom[31];
n = 15;
mat = RandomReal[{0.001, 0.5}, {n, n}];
Do[bbMM1[i]=Transpose[Transpose[mat]/Total[mat]][[All, i]], {i,n}]    
HH1 = - Sum[Table[bbMM1[i][[j]]*Log[bbMM1[i][[j]]], {j, n}], {i, n}]
```

Obviously, `Do` loops and `Sum` do not look nice. I would like to have a function of the following form:

```
ShannonEntropy[#]&/@{mat1, mat2, mat3}
```

where `{mat1,mat2,mat3}` is a vector of matrices for which entropy are to be calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sE]
sE = Module[{m0 = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ Transpose[#]}, Total[-Log[m0] m0]] &;

sE[mat] == HH1
```

> True

Comment: In the `Do` loop format, I face this problem, leading to `Indeterminate` output. How do you handle `zeros` in the matrix used?

Comment: @Tugrul, if the input matrix can have 0 entries, you can try `sE = Quiet@
    Block[{Indeterminate = 0},  Module[{m0 = Normalize[#, Total[#, 2] &] &@Transpose[#]},  Total[-Log[m0] m0]]] &;`

Comment: Thank you for the code. It smoothly workd for many matrices at one go. Thanks.